# Laravel - Check if user has commented on an article

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am learning Laravel and having a problem. I do not know how to check if user has commented on an article in the official way. I have `User`, `Article` and `Comment` model.

**User Relations:**

```
|_ articles() returning hasMany('Article')
|_ comments() returning morphMany('Comment')
```

**Comment Relations:**

```
|_ commentable() returning morphTo()
```

**Article Relations:**

```
|_ user() returning belongsTo('User')
|_ comments() returning morphMany('Comment')
```

Now when I am iterating over each article, I'm doing like this to check if user has commented on this post:

```
@if(
    $article->comments()
    ->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
    ->where('commentable_id', '=', $article->id)
    ->where('commentable_type', '=', 'Article')
    ->count()
    > 0
)
```

Is it the right way? Where did Laravel's magic go? It looks wierd and the View becomes ugly.

Comment: If you are using Laravel's Models you want to request the relationship from the comment. But the way you are doing it at the moment will always be faster as it creates a direct SQL query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@if($post->comments()->where('user_id', $user->id)->count() > 0)
@endif
```

You could even write a little method in your article model:

```
public function hasCommentsFromUser($userId){
    return $this->comments()->where('user_id', $userId)->count() > 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
@if($post->hasCommentsFromUser($user->id)
@endif
```

### Update

You definitely have to eager load the comments. That means instead of just doing

```
$posts = Article::all();
```

You do:

```
$posts = Article::with('comments')->get();
```

This means that now every article object already has the comments loaded. Because of that, it doesn't make sense to use the code from the beginning of the answer because it would run a new query for every article.

Instead you can use `contains` with a closure to check the already existing collection:

```
public function hasCommentsFromUser($userId){
    return !is_null($this->comments->first(function($i, $comment) use ($userId){
        return $comment->user_id == $userId;
    }));
}
```

Comment: As said, I am learning Laravel. Eager Loading, I have read it in Docs but doesn't know :3. As far as "what I want to accomplish" is concerned, I am creating a premium social networking site so I really need to follow good coding standards and use professional code. Can we have a discussion?

Comment: Okay. I actually meant accomplish with this specific if statement... And do you need all comments of a post anyways? Maybe it helps if you post more of your view.

Comment: Yeah, I will show comments to the user. If user has commented, info will appear that you have also commented else `null`. The same logic applies to `Liking` an article so, I thought having a nice solution to comments check will help me in liking also and if needed somewhere else. You are trying to consider `performance` by asking whether I need to show them to user or not? I will never pull out comments just for providing extra info.

Comment: Can I do `chaining` of `with`? I also need to extract `likes`.

Comment: There is no such thing as private messages on Stack Overflow. Also I would rather not friend you on facebook. If you have a question ask it here and I will probably see it as I'm actively watching the [laravel] tag. If you want to bring my attention to a question of yours you could also leave a comment on this post and I will get a notification :)

Comment: Yes you can chain `with`. Or even better, you can do this: `->with('comments', 'likes')` and add as many as you need.

Comment: Hey come to chat again. I have a problem, actually your code has a problem.

Comment: Sorry I don't have time. You'll have to figure it out yourself

Comment: Ok bro. Let me figure it out ;)

Comment: I got it working. FYI, the `first()` methods closure gets two arguments. I think first one is integer and second one is the object of the model. It should be like this: `$this->comments->first( function($i, $comment) {})` not `$this->comments->first( function($comment) {})`

Comment: Ahhh right the first argument is the key and the second the model. Totally forgot about that.

Comment: Can't you ask a question here on SO?